# how to handle floating point values going beyond the range in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am writing a unigram naive bayes classifier in Python. I am calculating probabilities and multiplying those. Such cumulative multiplication is reducing the value to 0 after reaching some number. I am trying to get rid of extremely low values by removing stop words or not considering the denominator of prior in Naive Bayes classifier. 
I don't however, know how to make approximation or handle floating point values beyond the lower limit.Following is a snippet of code

```
for word in para:
            probofwordgivenclass=int(likelihood[key][word])
            if(probofwordgivenclass>10):
                mult=(float(probofwordgivenclass+1)/float(totalwordcount+vocabularsize))
                prob= prob*mult
```

In above code prob is cumulative probability. It reduces to 0 at the end. What approximations would you suggest? or how to handle it in Python?

Comment: The NLTK package already has a nice [`NaiveBayesClassifier`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html?highlight=naivebayes#nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier), why write own?

Comment: It's common to work with the logarithms of probabilities instead.

Comment: What Antti said. But if you do need to do high precision arithmetic in Python there's the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module. And if you want arbitrary precision with a whole bunch of advanced functions, see [mpmath](http://mpmath.org).